# Simple tag as variable in template

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

I have a simple template tag:

```
@register.simple_tag
def my_simple_tag(key):
    return key
```

In *some* cases I need to use it as a variable in my template:

```
{% my_simple_tag "key" as key %}
```

but it give me an error:

```
'my_simple_tag' received too many positional arguments.
```

I don't want to use an `assignment_tag` that always requires to use **as**.

Comment: Seems this is now possible in Django 1.9

Answer (score 1):

'Simple tag' means exactly that. If you've got something that sometimes acts as an assignment tag and sometime as a simple tag, it's no longer simple, and you'll need to write your own Node and compilation function. The documentation explains at length how to do that.